# Parsing IP address and port in python

Tags: python, ip-address

Using python, I'd like to accomplish two things:

1. Need to split an ipv6 address and port combination in the format [fec2::10]:80 to fec2::10 and 80.
2. Given an IP address and port combination, I need to determine if the IP is a v4 or v6 address. Eg: 1.2.3.4:80 and [fec2::10]:80

Please suggest a way to do it.

Thanks!

Sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def main():
    server = "[fec1::1]:80"
    if server.find("[", 0, 2) == -1:
       print "IPv4"
       ip, port = server.split(':')
    else:
       print "IPv6"
       new_ip, port = server.rsplit(':', 1)
       print new_ip
       ip = new_ip.strip('[]')

    print ip
    print port

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works for all cases except when the input is specified without a port. Eg: 10.78.49.50 and [fec2::10]

Any suggestions to address this?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: My bash and python scripts would receive the IP:port combination as input and the scripts need to determine the address family of the IP, followed by splitting the IP and port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I came up with. It looks lengthy and laborious, but it addresses all possible input scenarios. Any suggestion to condense/better it is most welcome :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import optparse

def main():
    server = "[fec1::1]:80"

    if server.find("[", 0, 2) == -1:
       print "IPv4"
       if server.find(":", 0, len(server)) == -1:
          ip = server
          port = ""
       else:
          ip, port = server.split(':')
    else:
       print "IPv6"
       index = server.find("]", 0, len(server))
       if index == -1:
          print "Something wrong"
          new_ip = ""
          port = ""
       else:
          if server.find(":", index, len(server)) == -1:
             new_ip = server
             port = ""
          else:
             new_ip, port = server.rsplit(':', 1)
       print new_ip
       ip = new_ip.strip('[]')

    print ip
    print port

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `your_input` is like `"[fec2::10]:80"` or `"1.2.3.4:80"`, it is easy to split the port and find out the ip address:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from ipaddress import ip_address

ip, separator, port = your_input.rpartition(':')
assert separator # separator (`:`) must be present
port = int(port) # convert to integer
ip = ip_address(ip.strip("[]")) # convert to `IPv4Address` or `IPv6Address` 
print(ip.version) # print ip version: `4` or `6`
```

Comment: The [`ipaddress`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module is only new as of 3.3, what if someone is running an earlier version of python? I do think that finding the version is simpler this way, though, don't get me wrong. :)

Comment: @2rs2ts: you could use [`ipaddr-py`](https://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/) on earlier versions.

Comment: Ah, nice to know. It's still not part of the standard modules, though.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I'm unable to use both ipaddress and ipaddr-py modules in my script. For ipaddress, it says:                       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ip_parse.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ipaddress import ip_address
ImportError: No module named ipaddress

    from ipaddress import ip_address

Comment: ...and for ipaddr-py, it says:    File "./ip_parse.py", line 5
    from ipaddr-py import ip_address
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I've added a module-independent code that I wrote, to my question. It is incomplete. Any suggestions for it?

Comment: @Maddy: this answer might be too complex for. You either should be able to install Python 3.3 or download [`ipaddress.py` file from `ipaddr-py` distribution](https://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/source/browse/branches/3144/ipaddress.py) and put it in the same directory as the script.

Comment: This does not work when the port is missing.

Comment: @MarcH the question requires the port to be present. The explicit example inputs and the assert also point to it. The answer shouldn't work when the port is missing

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) (called `urllib.parse` in 3.x) to separate the URL into each of its components:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> ipv4address = urlparse("http://1.2.3.4:80")
>>> ipv4address
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='1.2.3.4:80', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> ipv6address = urlparse("http://[fec2::10]:80")
>>> ipv6address
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='[fec2::10]:80', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Then you can split the port off by finding the index of the last colon using [`rfind`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind):

```
>>> ipv4address.netloc.rfind(':')
7
>>> ipv4address.netloc[:7], ipv4address.netloc[8:]
('1.2.3.4', '80')
>>> ipv6address.netloc.rfind(':')
10
>>> ipv6address.netloc[:10], ipv6address.netloc[11:]
('[fec2::10]', '80')
```

Identifying which type it is should then be as simple as `if ':' in that_split_tuple[0]`, right? (Not 100% sure because it's been a while since I learned about how to write IPv6 addresses in URLs.)

Finally, removing the brackets from your IPv6 address is simple, there are many ways to do it:

```
>>> ipv6address.netloc[:10].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
'fec2::10'
>>> ipv6address.netloc[:10].strip('[]')
'fec2::10'
```

**Edit**: since you expressed concern about not always having port numbers, you could simplify significantly by using a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> f = lambda(n): re.split(r"(?<=\]):" if n.startswith('[') else r"(?<=\d):", n)
>>> f(ipv4address.netloc)
['1.2.3.4', '80']
>>> f(ipv6address.netloc)
['[fec2::10]', '80']
>>> f("1.2.3.4")
['1.2.3.4']
>>> f("[fec2::10]")
['[fec2::10]']
```

(I'm having trouble being more clever with my regular expression, hence the inline ternary.)

Comment: I've added a module-independent code that I wrote, to my question. It is incomplete. Any suggestions for it?

Comment: @Maddy Well, at this point I'll write a regular expression for you, but you need to tell me if you're always going to get brackets around your IPv6 addresses, and whether you're going to use hybrid addresses e.g. `::ffff:1.2.3.4`.

Comment: Almost perfect answer, missing a couple things: 1. no need to parse `netloc` manually and no need for any evil regular expression: `urlparse('//[::1]:123').hostname` -> `'::1'`  `urlparse('//[::1]').port` -> `None`. 2. No need for a full `http://`, the `urllib` documentation states that `//` is enough.

Comment: 3. Again no evil regular expression for this: `ipaddress.ip_address('::1')` ->
`IPv6Address('::1')`